# How to install pacparser in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, makefile, proxy

Following this guide https://github.com/pacparser/pacparser/blob/master/INSTALL on how to install pacparser, I have the following problem on the 8th step during compilation:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the compatible issues the python in your windows, you can try to either check your python environment configuration or swich to  Annaconda python environment and try it again..

Comment: I have installed both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. I also have Anaconda for Python 2.7. I have to use Python 2.7, should I remove the 3.4?